# problem with JsonConverter: can't convert Server TimeStamp to DateTime to replace FieldValue field

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the datetime from firestore but can't get jsonconverter work.
Note

```
const factory Note({
  required UniqueId id,
  required NoteBody body,
  required NoteColor color,
  required List3<TodoItem> todos,
  required bool archived,
  DateTime? timestamp,
}) = _Note;
```

NoteDto

```
const factory NoteDto({
  // ignore: invalid_annotation_target
  @JsonKey(includeFromJson: false) String? id,
  required String body,
  required int color,
  required List<TodoItemDto> todos,
  required bool archived,
  @ServerTimeStampConverter() required FieldValue? serverTimeStamp,
}) = _NoteDto;
```

NoteDto.fromDomain:

```
factory NoteDto.fromDomain(Note note) {
  return NoteDto(
    id: note.id.getOrCrash(),
    body: note.body.getOrCrash(),
    color: note.color.getOrCrash().value,
    todos: note.todos.getOrCrash().map((todoItem) {
      return TodoItemDto.fromDomain(todoItem);
    }).asList(),
    archived: note.archived,
    serverTimeStamp: FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  );
}
```

Note toDomain:

```
Note toDomain() {
  return Note(
    id: UniqueId.fromUniqueString(id!),
    body: NoteBody(body),
    color: NoteColor(Color(color)),
    todos: List3(todos.map((dto) => dto.toDomain()).toImmutableList()),
    archived: archived,
    timestamp: ?????, // don't know what to put here, it show error when I put serverTimeStamp!.toDate() 
  ); // error: The method 'toDate' isn't defined for the type 'FieldValue'.
// Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toDate'
}
```

NoteDto from Json and from Firestore:

```
factory NoteDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    _$NoteDtoFromJson(json);

factory NoteDto.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
  // log("doc: ${doc.get("serverTimeStamp")}");
  return NoteDto.fromJson(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>).copyWith(
    id: doc.id,
  );
}
```

ServerTimeStampConverter:

```
class ServerTimeStampConverter implements JsonConverter<FieldValue, Object> {
  const ServerTimeStampConverter();
  @override
  FieldValue fromJson(Object json) {
    return FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
  }

  @override
  Object toJson(FieldValue fieldValue) => fieldValue;
}
```

I tried to change the JsonConverter to:

```
class ServerTimeStampConverter implements JsonConverter<DateTime?, Object?> {
  const ServerTimeStampConverter();

  @override
  DateTime? fromJson(Object? json) {
    // log("FielValue.servertimestamp: ${.serverTimestamp()}");
    return (json as Timestamp).toDate();
  }

  @override
  Object? toJson(DateTime? dateTime) => FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
}
```

but it doesn't work, it failed when generating code

```
[SEVERE] json_serializable on lib/infrastructure/notes/note_dtos.dart:
Could not generate `fromJson` code for `serverTimeStamp`
......
199 │   final FieldValue? **serverTimeStamp**;
    │                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

When using Firebase, the Timestamp type is different from the DateTime type. To transform a Timestamp to a DateTime, you need to parse the timestamp and convert it. I see that you are using freezed and jsonSerializable, so I have provided some code that may help you.

```
const factory Note({
  required UniqueId id,
  required NoteBody body,
  required NoteColor color,
  required List3<TodoItem> todos,
  required bool archived,
  @JsonKey(fromJson: getDateTimeFromTimestamp, toJson: timeStampToJson)
     DateTime? timestamp,
}) = _Note;

DateTime? getDateTimeFromTimestamp(dynamic value) {
  if (value is Timestamp) {
    return value.toDate();
  }
  return null;
}

dynamic timeStampToJson(DateTime? value) {
  if (value != null){
  final timestamp = Timestamp.fromDate(value);
  return timestamp.toString();
  }
  return null;

}
```

I hope it helps!

Regards.